# php ob_end_flush() does not work

Tags: php, redirect

```
echo "First Login as a user.";
ob_end_flush();
flush();
usleep(5000000);
header("Location:index.php");
```

i want to display "First Login as a user." and after 5 seconds i want to redirect to `index.php`.

i found the above code and it should work. but when i run the code, there's no output. the browser title bar shows "connecting" and after 5 seconds directly redirects to `index.php`.

how to solve the error. is there any other method?
(tried sleep(), ob_flush() same result.)

Apache 2.4.4
PHP 5.5.1

another doubt:
is there anyway to combine these two statements.

```
isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user']!="admin"
```

Comment: Did you call `ob_start()` ?

Comment: @shuangwhywhy yes i called ob_start().

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Refresh header instead of flushing data:

```
header( "Refresh:5; url=index.php" );
echo "First Login as a user.";
// End Script
```

Also remember, Calling the header() function after outputting data will result in a "headers already sent" php error.. SO call header() first

Comment: does not work. only displays the text but doesn't redirect.
tried both in chrome 26 and firefox 22.0 thinking it a browser error. but no success.

Comment: Kind of a silly question, but do you have Javascript enabled?

Comment: yeah. javascript is enabled. and i'm using now refresh via `<meta>` tag. but it's possible to change the meta tag by firebug or any other editing tool. for that purpose i want to use php redirection.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be able to change headers *after* anything has been output to the browser. Also, relying on a sleep from the server before sending the redirect is not a good idea, as the user could lose connection or cancel the request. Also, the page is technically halted while the browser waits for the connection to finish.

The best solution would be to use the Refresh header as @Wilson212 mentions.

In regards to the combination of the isset() and string check, the way you have it is best practice. If you do not do a check for the variable being set, you will get warnings in PHP 5 typically. I would leave it how you have it currently for that line.